# Expected ')' before ',' token - SFML creating RectangleShape

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

When trying to create an member of the sf::RectangleShape class I get those compiler error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in wDraw (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
/window.h|15|error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token|
/window.h|15|error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token|
/window.h|15|error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration|
/window.h|15|error: redeclaration of ‘sf::RectangleShape window::window::y’|
/window.h|9|note: previous declaration ‘float 
/window.h|15|error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token|
/window.h|15|error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token|
/window.h|15|error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token|
/window.h|15|error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration|
/window.h|15|error: redeclaration of ‘sf::RectangleShape window::window::y’|
/window.h|9|note: previous declaration ‘float window::window::y’|
/window.h|15|error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token|
||=== Build failed: 10 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace window{
class window{
    private:
    public:
        float x=35.f;
        float y=35.f;
        sf::RenderWindow window;
        sf::RenderWindow tools;
        sf::RenderWindow colors;
        sf::RenderWindow file;
        sf::RenderWindow warning;
        sf::RectangleShape choosepen(sf::Vector2f(x,y));
        sf::RectangleShape chooseeraser;
        sf::RectangleShape chooserectangle;
        sf::RectangleShape choosetriangle;
        sf::RectangleShape choosecircle;
        sf::RectangleShape chooseline;
        sf::RectangleShape choosetext;
        sf::RectangleShape choosecolor;
        sf::Event events;
        void createwindow(int resx, int resy){
            window.create(sf::VideoMode(resx, resy), "MainWindow", sf::Style::Default);
            window.clear();
            window.display();
            }
        void createtools(){
            tools.create(sf::VideoMode(200,200), "Tools", sf::Style::Resize); tools.clear();
            tools.display();
        }
        void createcolors(){
            colors.create(sf::VideoMode(200,200), "Colors", sf::Style::Resize); colors.clear();
            colors.display();}
        void createfile(){
            file.create(sf::VideoMode(200,200), "File", sf::Style::Resize); file.clear();
            file.display();
        }
        void createwarning(){
            warning.create(sf::VideoMode(400,200), "Warning", sf::Style::Resize); warning.clear();
            warning.display();}

};
}
```

Also when trying this faulty fragment of code in different project I do not get those compiler errors.

Working project:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
float x=35.f;
float y=35.f;
sf::RectangleShape choosepen(sf::Vector2f(x,y));
}
```

I am using SMFL 2-2.5.1-23.83 with IDE being code::blocks 20.03. 
Thanks for all help

Comment: I assume this is line 15: `sf::RectangleShape choosepen(sf::Vector2f(x,y));`

Answer (score 0):

`sf::RectangleShape choosepen(sf::Vector2f(x,y))` inside a class definition tries to be parsed as a member function which receives `sf::Vector2f` as a parameter and returns `sf::RectangleShape`. Something like `sf::RectangleShape choosepen(sf::Vector2f parameter) { return whatever; }`.

As a general solution to [such problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), you can use [uniform initialization](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es23-prefer-the--initializer-syntax): `sf::RectangleShape choosepen{sf::Vector2f{x, y}}`.